# mlock stacking in linux

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

If the same process locks two addresses sharing part of the same page in the memory. Will unlocking one address unlock the shared page? The documentation on lock stacking is pretty unclear about this after the recent version of linux kernel allowing unprivileged processes to lock memory.

Answer (score 2):

- Memory locks do not stack, that is, pages which have been locked several times by calls to mlock() or mlockall() will be unlocked by a single call to munlock() for the corresponding range or by munlockall().
- Pages which are mapped to several locations or by several processes stay locked into RAM as long as they are locked at least at one location or by at least one process.

**Reference** : Notes of [mlock(2) man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mlock).

Comment: It is still unclear. So suppose i have two addresses say from page 1 to half of page 2 and other from second half of page 2 to say end of page 2. What happens if i lock address 1, then address 2 and then unlock address 1.

Comment: Pages are locked/unlocked in their entirety. In your scenario, the `mlock(p1)` call will lock both the pages 1 and 2. And the `munlock(p2)` call will unlock ONLY page2. Page 1 will be unlocked ONLY after the `munlock(p1)` corresponding to the first `mlock(p1)` is executed.

Comment: Mine case is mlock(a1) {locks page 1 and 2}, mlock(a2) {page 2 is already locked}, munlock(a1). Will this unlock both pages 1 and 2?

Comment: Following the above operations, Page1 will always be unlocked. Page2 will be unlocked ONLY if all the ops are executed in the same process. Page2 will remain locked if the `mlock(a2)` was called from a different process.

Comment: Pages which are mapped to several locations or by several processes stay locked into RAM as long as they are locked at least at one location or by at least one process.

Comment: This is the thing which confuses me. So if mlock(a2) was called from a different process then page 2 will remain locked after the above operations. If mlock(a2) was called from the same process then page 2 will be unlocked after the above operations (even munlock(a2) is not called yet) ?

Comment: Also what do you mean by pages mapped to several locations?  Isn't that the case above as page 2 is mapped to both a1 and a2 (which are different)?

Comment: Yes. Stacking behaviour differs depending on whether the same or different process(es) mlock/munlock.

Comment: Also the same physical page can be addressed by two different virtual addresses in two different processes. In this scenario, as long as one of the virtual addresses is locked using `mlock()`, the page stays locked in memory even if the other virtual address is `munlock()`ed.